# wordpress: remove image upload options while adding new post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image: Options to be removed]

I want to remove the two options (as illustrated in the image) while uploading images.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial for what you're asking - http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/remove-wordpress-defaultmedia-image-sizes/